# Kitkat 4.4 ANR errors after publish

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-anr-dialog

guys i have two questions:
1) how to test complete app (i mean run test, not unit) on each api from minSDK version which i set up. Is it any auto process for that?
2) after publish my app i have ANR error on my app publish console (system run 4.4 Kitkat):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5011)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4582)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4522)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method:0)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4996)
```

i set up avd emulator with similar config on my android studio i after compile i have below exception:

```
1829-2839/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/LoadManifestTask: Can't find Chimera operation impl class com.google.android.location.copresence.GcmRegistrationChimeraReceiver dropping operation
                                                                                   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.location.copresence.GcmRegistrationChimeraReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar", zip file "/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar", zip file "/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk.classes2.zip", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk.classes3.zip", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk.classes4.zip", zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/code_cache/secondary-dexes/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk.classes5.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                                       at bws.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:799)
                                                                                       at bwt.run(:com.google.android.gms:2049)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)


                                                                                   [ 05-25 03:04:16.195  1623: 1638 D/         ]
                                                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9183a30, tid 1638
```

Any Idea what cuse this problem?
My app work fine on Lollipop and Nugat. 
I paste also my gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.fff.hhh'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 8
        versionName '4.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}
```

Comment: Are you checking availability of Play Services before using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described official [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

> You are strongly encouraged to use the `GoogleApiClient` class to
>   access Google Play services features. This approach allows you to
>   attach an `OnConnectionFailedListener` object to your client. To
>   detect if the device has the appropriate version of the Google Play
>   services APK, implement the `onConnectionFailed()` callback method. If
>   the connection fails due to a missing or out-of-date version of the
>   Google Play APK, the callback receives an error code such as
>   `SERVICE_MISSING`, `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED`, or
>   `SERVICE_DISABLED`. ... Another approach is to use the
>   `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` method. You get a reference to the
>   singleton object that provides this method using
>   `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()`. You might call this method in
>   the `onResume()` method of the main activity. If the result code is
>   `SUCCESS`, then the Google Play services APK is up-to-date and you can
>   continue to make a connection.

Please make sure you're following these rules.

Answer (score 0):

To test the app against the particular version :

```
1. Write espresso test 
2. run those tests on the device with desired api level
```

To solve the gcm problem  Add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the end of your build.gradle you have pasted above.

Comment: android studio say that "11:41 Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found."